# plotting error in 3D

Tags: error-propagation

What is the problem related to the following plot?

**Definition of geometry**

```
RR = ImplicitRegion[((Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 9))^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
```

Comment: Shouldn't you tell us the problem and ask us to fix it?

Comment: Please keep your original question,don't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `z=0.1` and creat a 2D `ImplicitRegion` instead of 3D `ImplicitRegion`

At the same time the `SliceDensityPlot3D` also need to set `z == 0.1`

```
Table[DensityPlot[
  funs[[i]][x, y, 0.1], {x, y} ∈ 
   ImplicitRegion[((Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 9))^2 + .1^2 <= 1, {x, y}], 
  PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 4}]

Table[SliceDensityPlot3D[funs[[i]][x, y, z], z == 0.1, 
  Element[{x, y, z}, RR], PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals[[i]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal"], {i, Length[vals]}]
```

[image]

[image]

It seems that `DensityPlot3D` some times faster than 2D?

```
DensityPlot3D[funs[[3]][x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ RR]
```